Upgrade 22 to 24 problem: "Failed to download repository information"
After "sudo apt update-manager -c"
I get "Failed to download repository information".
sudo apt update gives 2 errors:

... lyx-devel/release/ubuntu ... does not have a Release file
... zoneminder-1.34/ubuntu ... does not have a Release file

but I have no idea what if anything I can do about this.
I think I can remove lyx-devel - don't use lyx now.
I do use zoneminder though - I could get something else if necessary.
